# Photoshop Borderless printing doesnt seem possible

Tags: printing, printer, adobe-photoshop, photoshop-cs6

I am using **Windows 8.1 pro** with **Photoshop CS6 Extended**
I have an **HP Envy 120** Printer (capable of Borderless Printing)

I have tried adjusting many different settings within Photoshop and via the printers own interface.

I can see that when adjusting the printer settings within its own interface, it does affect the *print preview* box in **Photoshop**, Apparently you will only achieve *borderless* printing when the *crosshatch* section I have highlighted in the image below disappears (something I can not get it to do)

I have ensured that

- My canvas size is correct and fits the aspect ratio (210 x 297 millimeters) **A4**
- My printer is set to print Portrait
- My printer's paper size is set to **A4**
- Borderless does work in my printer - I did this by printing from a USB attached to my printer, when doing this it prints borderless.

[image]

**UPDATE** - Added following image for Mark Ransom comment

[image]

Comment: If you scroll down what's under "Position and Size"?

Comment: @MarkRansom Updated my post, please see above.

Comment: Try hitting the "bleed" button.

Comment: @MarkRansom didnt seem to work, tired multiple bleed witdths and reprinting

Comment: Try the "Advanced" button on the printer driver then.

Comment: @MarkRansom Hitting advanced is what brings up the box to the right of that window, **a4**, **max dpi enabled** etc...

Comment: In that case I'd have to say that the printer driver is missing some crucial options. Not surprising, HP has never been known for driver quality.

Answer (score -1):

It looks like you need to set your paper size to A4 (Borderless) in the Canon print settings, not the normal A4.

I had the same issue and just figured it out now.

Comment: That's wonderful, but please read the question again carefully. Your answer does **not** answer the original question. The OP has an HP printer, so your answer is useless.